# Jquery slide from top to bottom and bottom to top on dis-activate the button

Tags: jquery, html, css

i got struck at jquery drop down menu hide and show, please look into the link below, here please click Jobs tab, then click any of the sub menu button, it will show super sub menu, then please click "---" button, you can see that super sub menu will not hide from bottom to top, rather than it will hide from right to left..

Am looking that supper sub menu to hide from bottom to top on clicking "---" button tab, Please advice?

[JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/qijolive/1/edit)

Note: Auto-run JS should be enabled at jsbin, otherwise drop down will not enable...

Answer (score 1):

Try this with `.slideUp()` instead of `.hide()` on click of your `#collapse` link button:

```
$('#collapse').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if($(this).hasClass('active') == 0){
       $(this).hide(300);
       $('.submenu li a').removeClass('active');
       $('.all-menu').slideUp(300);
       $('.all-menu-new').slideUp(300);
       $('.all-menu-unass').slideUp(300);   
       $('.new-menu').slideUp(300);
       $('.all-menu-active').slideUp(300);
    }else{
      // $('.all-menu-unass').show(300);    
    }
});
```

[JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/livovota/1/edit)

Comment: Also, on multiple clicks on jobs button or any sub menus button at same time, it show sliding multiple times based on multiple clicks,but am looking for, sliding should be only once irrespective of multiple clicks, Please advice?

Comment: You can use `.stop()` method this way:  `$('.all-menu').stop(true, true).slideUp(300);` you can assign it before your `.hide()` methods.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, i tried this, but not working, could you please provide me JSBIN link as earlier if possible, so that it can be better understanding for me...

Answer (score 0):

I have checked your link , your code is working fine and perfect , the problem is not with your code but with your browser , try different browser, i have tested your code with latest chrome browser it is working fine , by clicking "----" button the super sub menu hide from bottom to top